# Java Random Color String

Tags: java, random, colors

I have written this java method but sometimes the color String is only 5 characters long. Does anyone know why?

```
@Test
public void getRandomColorTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        final String s = getRandomColor();
        System.out.println("-> " + s);
    }
}

 public String getRandomColor() {
    final Random random = new Random();
    final String[] letters = "0123456789ABCDEF".split("");
    String color = "#";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.round(random.nextFloat() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `random.nextInt(16)` instead of `Math.round(random.nextFloat() * 15)`?

Comment: Instead of `color += letters[Math.round(random.nextFloat() * 15)];` use `color += letters[random.nextInt(letters.length)];`

Answer (score 32):

Working with floats and using `round` is not a safe way of creating such random colors.

Actually a color code is an integer in hexadecimal formatting. You can easily create such numbers like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class R {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // create random object - reuse this as often as possible
        Random random = new Random();
        
        // create a big random number - maximum is ffffff (hex) = 16777215 (dez)
        int nextInt = random.nextInt(0xffffff + 1);
        
        // format it as hexadecimal string (with hashtag and leading zeros)
        String colorCode = String.format("#%06x", nextInt);
        
        // print it
        System.out.println(colorCode);
    }

}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://www.online-java.com/C7mQ9hNAtI)</kbd>

Comment: Plus one, for taking the time to understand what the OP *really* wants and submitting a far better approach.

Comment: This was as easy as copy/paste and it works great.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your `split` will generate an array of length 17 with an empty string at the beginning. Your generator occasionally draws that zeroth element which will not contribute to the length of the final string. (As a side effect, `F` will never be drawn.)

1. Accept that `split` has that odd behaviour and work with it: Ditch that nasty formula that uses `round`. Use `1 + random.nextInt(16)` instead as your index.
2. **Don't** recreate the generator on each call of `getRandomColor`: that ruins the generator's statistical properties. Pass `random` as a parameter to `getRandomColor`.

Comment: but `nextFloat` generates a number from 0 to 1, hence you should never get 15.5 or even 16 with the multiplication. Btw. shouldn't this throw an index out bounds instead?

Comment: @ctst: Oops, had that `split` behaviour the wrong way round in my head and invented an answer to fit. It's correct now.

Answer (score 2):

Also to ensure that your String always contains 6 characters, try to replace the `for` loop with a `while`. Please see:

```
while (color.length() <= 6){
    color += letters[random.nextInt(17)];
}
```

Comment: It should be `random.nextInt(16)`.